# Lodash groupby multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this Input

```js
var data = [
  { 
   'group': 
    {
     'id': 1,
     'name': 'admin'
    }, 
    'role': 'name1', 
    'screen': {
      'info': 'white',
      'name': 'Cat'
    }  
  },
  { 
   'group': 
    {
     'id': 1,
     'name': 'admin'
    }, 
    'role': 'name2',   
    'screen': {
      'info': 'Grey',
      'name': 'Dog'
    }  
  },
  { 
   'group': 
    {
     'id': 2,
     'name': 'client'
    }, 
    'role': 'name3',   
    'screen': {
      'info': 'Grey',
      'name': 'goldfish'
    }  
  }
];
//obj=>JSON.stringify({age: obj.age, address: obj.details[0].address})
//obj=>JSON.stringify({group: obj.name, displayname: obj})
var result=_.chain(data).groupBy("group.name").map(function(v, i) {
  return {
    group: i,
    role: _.get(_.find(v, 'role'), 'role'),
    screen: _.map( v, 'screen'),
  }
}).value();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, '  ') + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And here is my output I want: `[
  {
    "group": "admin",
    "screen": [
        {
            "role": "name1",
            "ui": {
                "info": "white",
                "name": "Cat"
            }
       },
       {
            "role": "name2",
            "ui": {
                "info": "Grey",
                "name": "Dog"
            }
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "client",
    "screen": [
        {
            "role": "name3",
            "ui": {
                "info": "Grey",
                "name": "goldfish"
            }
        }
    ]
  }
]`

Any help from all you always helpful with me. Thank you. :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qx4tajL6/5055/ This is my current code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the map's callback function to manually create the result screen object:

```js
var data = [{"group":{"id":1,"name":"admin"},"role":"name1","screen":{"info":"white","name":"Cat"}},{"group":{"id":1,"name":"admin"},"role":"name2","screen":{"info":"Grey","name":"Dog"}},{"group":{"id":2,"name":"client"},"role":"name3","screen":{"info":"Grey","name":"goldfish"}}];

var result = _(data)
  .groupBy("group.name")
  .map(function(v, group) {
    return {
      group,
      screen: _.map(v, function(o) {
        return {
          role: o.role,
          ui: o.screen
        };
      }),
    }
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like this answer very much @Ori Drori

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Absolutely  @Ori Drori:D